# Retrieve and display the data in php posted from client side cURL code

Tags: php, curl

I am new to php.I need to post the xml contents to https server and retrieve the posted data back in the server side using PHP.I am using the CURL code in the below link for client side code

```
http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/post-callback.html
```

Only difference is,I am posting the data to PHP instead of CGI.

In the server side I configured a server using Apache.How to retrieve back the posted data there using php.I tried something in the php.Herewith I am attaching the php.

```
<?php
echo "testing\n";
$foo =htmlspecialchars($_GET['ptr']);

if($foo== "test")
{
echo "test string received";
}
else
{
echo "Not yet reached";
}

?>
```

I am posting the String "test" only.But I am always getting the response as "Not yet Reached from server side".How to check the data what we send,Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see any CURL code

Comment: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/post-callback.html.I modified the code from the above link only.

Comment: If you are POSTing values, then of course you don’t find them in $_GET …

Comment: Then how can I retrieve the data back in the server side?